# Trying to put server name into a URL for email template

Tags: email, email-template

I am using a visual force template.  I can put the origin server in the email by doing:

```
{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}
```

and when I an email sent I'll see:

```
https://na11-api.salesforce.com
```

However, when I try to use this in a URL which pulls in an image, I do:

```
<img src= "{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015G0000001f7xo&oid=00DG0000000gUxRMAU" height="90"/>
```

I get:

```
Error:      VFTemplate1 line 13, column 154: The reference to entity "oid" must end with the ';' delimiter  
Error   Error: The reference to entity "oid" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

So I try escaping the " " characters around the com by doing:

```
<img src= "{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND(\".com/\",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015G0000001f7xo&oid=00DG0000000gUxRMAU" height="90"/>
```

And, I get same error. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the salesforce base URL rather than the API URL?

Comment: @techrekker From my testing either work. but if it is easier to get the base URL, and it works I'd go for that.

Comment: Seems like the error is to do with URL encoding. Have you tried using the URLFOR function within an apex:image which could work better http://salesforcesource.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html?m=1

Comment: @techrekker good idea but that API is usually used with static resource. I am sending an email and the general advice is to make your image a document rather than a static resource when doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by hanging the `"` to `'` around some of the parsing.:

```
<img src= "{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015G0000001f7xo&oid=00DG0000000gUxRMAU" height="90"/>
```

Works with `img` and `apex:image`