# vf email template - detail Link

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template

In HTML email template, we can use `{!Lead.Link}` option to access the url inside salesforce.

But i found this `{!Lead.Link}` can't be used in vf email template. I tried using `{!relatedTO.Link}`. But this shows error as:

> Invalid field Link for SObject Lead

Any idea like how to get this field accessed in vf email template.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a "clean" way to do this. But this seems to be a fairly popular hack:

```
<a href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_280, FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_280)+3)}/{!relatedTo.Id}">
    {!relatedTo.Name}
</a>
```

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096wuIAA
- [Trying to put server name into a URL for email template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/trying-to-put-server-name-into-a-url-for-email-template)

Comment: I usedthe same.But i'm checking for more clean options if there are any.

Comment: In apex there's `URL.toExternalForm()` call available but it would mean your VF email template needs to use a component (and that component would have the apex class as controller). Not worth the effort I'd say...

Comment: Have you tried this:
     
    Link : <a href="{!RelatedTo.Link}">{!relatedTo.Link}</a><br/>

Comment: `{!relatedTo.Link}` won't work in VF email templates.

Comment: these links dont seem to be picked up by the salesforce mobile app...hard to row in one direction.