# <Apex:OutputLink> Tag not generating link in Visualforce email template

Tags: apex, vf-email-template

I have a Visualforce Email template which is as below:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Pricing tool ticketing requested 
    {!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.S_Price__r.Name} 
    {!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.P_GateType__c}" 
recipientType="User" relatedToType="pkg__Approvals__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
  <h4>{!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.P_GateType__c} has been requested for Pricing
  <br/>{!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.S_Price__r.S_TicketingPriceIdentifier__c} 
      - {!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.S_Price__r.Name}.<br/>. 
  <br/>
  Please review and approve the request here:  <br/>
  <apex:outputLink value="{!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.Id}" id="theLink">
         {!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.Name}
  </apex:outputLink>
  </h4>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I am expecting the Link with apex:outputLink, However, it generates the email as below:

```
12345 - Pricing details.

Please review and approve the request here:
[a513O000000U89UQA0]12345 - Pricing details - 05.01.2023
```

Any help to get the Link would be highly appreciated. On a side note, this was working fine a few days before in my sandbox and was tested. It is not working only since very recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:outputLink>` `value=` [has to render to a valid https:// address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm?q=outputlink) to the SFDC record defined by:

```
 {!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__r.Id}
```

*(which by the way, is the same as `{!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__c}`*

Since this is an email template, you can't use relative addresses as the user will be clicking on it outside of SFDC (from within their email client)

So, the `value=` attribute needs to be (see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/vf-email-template-detail-link)):

```
{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_560,
       FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_560)+3)}/{!relatedTo.S_TicketingTool__c}"
```